# MAILTO is not sending mail to my email

Tags: linux, bash

what I'm trying to make is

1. Installation of MYSQL
2. Create a database named "important_files" with tables "data1" "data2" "data3"
3. Create a folder in /opt named “incremental-backup", “full-backup" and “dump_backup”
4. Backup the database "important_files” in the folder “dump_backup” every 5 minutes (ARCHIVE THE DUMP_BACKUP FOLDER)
5. Create a script that will:

   - backup the dump_backup folder using incremental method.
   - backup the dump_backup folder using full backup method.
   - Will notify gilroy.toledano@toro.io via e-mail

     Note: The archive folder should only contain the files and no extra directories.

This is my `crontab -e` configuration:

```
MAILTO=toro.guinto@gmail.com
*/1 * * * * tar -czf /opt/dump-backup/backup_.tar -C /var/lib/mysql/ important_files
*/1 * * * * tar -czf tar -czf /opt/full-backup/fullbackup_.tar -C /opt/ dump-backup
```

I've done all the possible solution including mutt mailx  etc. But none are working.

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: the problem is I'm not recieving email for example i use
echo "Please find attached the backup file" | mutt -a "/opt/backup.sh" -s "File attached" -- toro.ian.guinto@gmail.com